# Cannot access an individual item in JSON response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to access the user_agent field in this JSON response.

```
[
{
"created_at": "2022-04-07T15:15:54Z",
"session_id": "4cb28762d7e5f8426b32aa4d5cc340a4",
"url": "",
"context_type": "User",
"asset_type": null,
"controller": "users",
"action": "user_dashboard",
"interaction_seconds": null,
"updated_at": "2022-04-07T15:15:54Z",
"developer_key_id": null,
"user_request": null,
"render_time": 0.827914,
"user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36",
"asset_user_access_id": null,
"participated": false,
"summarized": null,
"http_method": "get",
"remote_ip": "",
"id": "92094b31-29d2-4d74-aee4-1dcb04c3b5a0",
"contributed": false,
"links": {
"user": 141709,
"context": 141709,
"asset": null,
"real_user": 138170000004599420,
"account": 584
},
"app_name": null
}
]
```

Here is the current code I have written

```
    id = row[0]
    url = f"{endpoint}/api/v1/users/{id}/page_views"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    rsd = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
    print(rsd)
    browser = json.loads(rsd)
    print(browser["user_agent"])
```

When ever I run it, I get a key error off user_agent. I have searched and searched but I cannot find a solution that will work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems very unlikely to be a real bug as presented in the code here. Why are you doing round-trip marshalling once you have a JSON response? Does `"user_agent"` exist in `response.json()`? Are you sure you don't have a typo in the key name?

Comment: Hey! When I try to print(response["user_agent"]) it gives me that it is not subscriptable. So I then did the json.dump but it gave me string indices must be integers. Finally, i did json.loads to get to the key error. I am positive that it doesn't have a spelling type. I copied the exact field from the response.

Comment: Can you remove json.dumps() and print the result you get from browser lets see

Comment: `json.dumps` turns a JSON object (i.e., a dictionary) into a string. `json.loads` turns a string into a JSON object. You're doing a lot of unnecessary work. If `response.json()` doesn't throw an error, that means `response.json()` is valid JSON which you can index.

Comment: Removed json.dumps and got this: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

Comment: Very explicitly, does `response.json()["user_agent"]` work? You have JSON so you don't need to turn it back into JSON.

Comment: Your JSON response is now a list... `response.json()[0]["user_agent"]`. I recommend thinking carefully about the types of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment this post I need to post it like an answer.... I did try to replicate an issue on my side but I wasn't able to do it since it printed user_agent properly. Can you please post results after printing the whole 'browser' object instead of trying to print only "user_agent" since I strongly believe that you are not getting what you expect to get with browser object.

Comment: Updated the post to show the full response

Comment: Thank you, I was able to replicate it now, but after printing it like this it's working: 

`print(browser[0]['user_agent'])`

Comment: When I run it, it returns a key error on the 0.

    id = row[0]
    url = f"{endpoint}/api/v1/users/{id}/page_views"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    rsd = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
    browser = json.loads(rsd)
    print(browser[0]['user_agent'])

Comment: I'm not able to understand how it can't find user_agent key there... since you sent output after `print(browser)` I created same json and I was able to pull data properly...

Is there *maybe* some dummy endpoint that returns the same value that's public so I can try to work with it?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Ok in that case let me just confirm that everything until now is clear on my side:

When you modified your code to look like this:

`id = row[0]
    url = f"{endpoint}/api/v1/users/{id}/page_views"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    rsd = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4)
    print(rsd)
    browser = json.loads(rsd)
    print(browser)
`

You were getting response that you posted as first item in this post?

Comment: Yup that is what I’m doing.